# Forcing IE to clear an image

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-7

I have an image tag that is in a popup.  This popup shows an image dependent on what the user clicks.  The popup gets closed (this just hides the popup, it doesn't remove anything from the DOM), then a new item is clicked, and the popup gets reshown, and the src attribute of the image is changed to the new one.

The problem I am having is that in IE, it will keep the old image until the new one is downloaded.  Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but the image is a call to a handler which can take a few seconds.  I was able to fix this in IE8 and IE9 by setting the src attribute to empty, then setting it to the handler.  This correctly cleared out the image before inserting the new one.

This solution did not work in IE7 though.  I'm planning on using a small clear gif as the src instead of empty, so that it will quickly swap out the image and then start loading the next one.  I am going to add an image tag to the page so that it gets cached in the users browser to make the image loading near instant.  Does this sound like a good solution?  Are there any major drawbacks or caveats that I am overlooking?

It's hacky, and I would REALLY like a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the IMG tag from the DOM and reinsert it before swapping the SRC.

Alternately, you could use [a data URI](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/) and use a blank image, encoded as Base64.

Comment: It looks like IE7 does not support data URIs - so that wouldn't help me in this case.  Simply removing the image and reinserting it is a legitimate option, though does it offer any benefits over what I was planning to implement?

Comment: Yes, you do not need top make another HTTP request.